# Input impedance of non inverting opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: Non inverting amplifier]

My question is, how can I calculate the input impedance of this circuit? I want to find the expression, that describes the input impedance.

Comment: Use maths and yes, it will be a tad complex but if you pay attention to what you are doing you'll get there.

Comment: Since small positive feedback is used it reduces the current load on input by the (1+ |-gain|) Thus get voltage ratio of 2 stage filter and subtract  from node as a current reduction on intermediate node.  using KCL to find input current divided into Vin

Comment: So you are asking for the input impedance of the whole circuit - and not only for the opamp (as indicated in the title), correct?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 3):

You've posted a Sallen-Key Band-Pass Filter. Personally I'd avoid doing the math -- The way I would approach it is to build the circuit in LTSpice then plot V(in)/I(in) vs. Frequency to get a plot of the input impedance vs. frequency.

That said, you can gain some insight by considering extreme cases when

frequency->infinity

and frequency->DC.

As f->inf, you're going to see R1 looking in as C shorts to ground.
As f->DC your C's are like open-circuits. The V+ terminal of the op-amp will be pulled to ground through R2 so the output of the op-amp will be 0V, so it will be like R3 is connected to ground. Thus, looking in at DC you'll see R1 + R3.